# Is it possible to pre-configure Windows 10 before installation?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, administration, silent-install

For example, I would like to set some Registry variables or Group Policies to custom values without breaking the system (e.g. `ProgramFilesDir` in Registry, Update policies, etc.). Will Windows use these new values for installation? Is it possible to create a configuration file with such changes and use it for Windows 10 silent deploy?

Comment: [Sysprep (System Preparation) Overview | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview)

Comment: Easier than sysprep if you wish it>>>>>>>https://sourceforge.net/projects/windows-10-lite/

Comment: @Moab thanks. It is abandoned a year ago though. Will it cause any issues? It also has too many unsolved issue tickets.

Comment: Yeah they quit development because of the constant W10 changes. All I can say is try it on a test PC.

Comment: I can recommend NTLite as a great software to modify windows installation images.